# Wix Webservice reference

Tags: vb.net, web-services, windows-services, wix

I have added a Service Reference in my Windows Service project and I use Wix to install.
When I use Wix for installation the call to the service doesn't work at all.
When using InstallUtil in VS2010 it works fine...
I am using Wix 3.8.1128.0.

```
<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Component Id="IA_service"  Guid="SOME GUID">
      <File Id="IA_service.exe" Name="IA_service.exe" Source="..\IA_service\bin\Release\IA_service.exe" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      <File Id="Mysql.Data.dll" Name="Mysql.Data.dll" Source="..\IA_service\bin\Release\Mysql.Data.dll" />
      <ServiceInstall Id="IA_service" Type="ownProcess" Name="IA_service" DisplayName="IA_service" Description="Some description" Start="auto" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal">
        <util:PermissionEx User="Everyone" ServicePauseContinue="yes" ServiceQueryStatus="yes" ServiceStart="yes" ServiceStop="yes" ServiceUserDefinedControl="yes" />
      </ServiceInstall>
      <ServiceControl Id="IA_service" Stop="both" Remove="both" Name="IA_service" Wait="no" />
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Doesn't work how, what errors are seen / logged?

Comment: No errors at all, it's just not getting past the requestcode.